# How to reference object data structure in nested method definition?

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

```js
function FormHistory()
{
  this.list = [];
  this.restoreFromFile = function()
  {
    console.log('Restoring History From File');
    fs.readFile('FormHistory.txt', function(err, data) {
      if(err) throw error;
      this.list = data.toString().split("\n");
    });
  }
}
```

I can confirm that data holds the correct information from the text file, and that the split is tokenizing the file correctly. However, I seem to be running into a problem due to trying to reference this.list inside of a callback from readFile().

How do I reference the list? Do I have to pass it to the callback?

Comment: put `var self = this` in the outer function and refer to `self` instead of `this` inside the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem because your callback function create a new scope, so the `this` in your callback function does not hold a reference to `this.list`.

**First approach**

You can save your context in a variable and then use this variable into your callback function.

```
function FormHistory()
{      
//Save the parent context
      var self = this;
      this.list = [];
      this.restoreFromFile = function()
      {
        console.log('Restoring History From File');
        fs.readFile('FormHistory.txt', function(err, data) {
          if(err) throw error;
          //use the parent context in the callback function
          self.list = data.toString().split("\n");
        });
      }
}
```

**Second approach : ES6 to the rescue**

A new feature from ES6 is the **arrows**. 
Unlike functions, arrows **share** the **same this** as their surrounding code.

So, your code becomes :

```
function FormHistory()
{
  this.list = [];
  this.restoreFromFile = function()
  {
    console.log('Restoring History From File');
    fs.readFile('FormHistory.txt', (err, data) => {
      if(err) throw error;
      //The "this" refers to the parent context, there is no new context
      this.list = data.toString().split("\n");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.list = data.toString().split("\n");
```

The 'this' in the above line makes reference to the readFile callback context, NOT the FormHistory() context. You must have a reference somewhere or bind the callback.

```
function FormHistory()
{
  var self = this;
  this.list = [];
  this.restoreFromFile = function()
  {
    console.log('Restoring History From File');
    fs.readFile('FormHistory.txt', function(err, data) {
      if(err) throw error;
      self.list = data.toString().split("\n");
    });
  }
}
```